# hibernate mapping confusion

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Could someone explain  me why this doesn't work? I want to have a table that contains informations about two users who played with each other. This doesn't work.

```
Public class History implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private UserDetails player1;

    @ManyToOne
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private UserDetails player2;

    @ManyToOne
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private UserDetails winner;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date time;

}
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Next time you ask a question. Don't just say "it doesn't work". Say **how** it doesn't work. Explain what you are doing, what is the result you expect, and what is the result you get. If you get an exception, post its full stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Column` is used to specify the mapping of a basic type. To specify the mapping of an association to another entity, you use a `@JoinColumn` (or a `@JoinTable`, depending on what you want):

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
private UserDetails player1;
```